# How to create a button on click the background color changes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JwHl.jpg)
Check image

I tried using button and on click event to change the background color. Also I don't know how to add the check icon on click and also how to return it to default state clicking the next button

Comment: thats a recycler view not a static button

Comment: How do I code it?

Comment: [Chips in Material Design3 android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set index to -1 initially and when you click the item it will change color of particular item

```
index=-1;

public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                index=position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if(index==position){
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        else
        {
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

    }
```